# why my double quoted list elements changed to single quote after modification?

Tags: python, list, methods

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames
# using as many lines of code as your chosen method requires.
newfilenames = [i.replace("hpp","h") for i in filenames]

print(newfilenames)
```

my output is `['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'h.out']`

my required out is `["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]`

which means in the above single quote i need to replace it with double quote.

Comment: In terms of syntax, there is no difference between single and double quotes, so both outputs are functionally identical.

Comment: They didn't change; you are looking that the *representation* of the list elements, since `str(newfilesnames)` uses `repr` (not `str`) to get a string representation for each element of the list.

Comment: Your required output looks a lot like JSON, which means you should be using `print(json.dumps(newfilenmes))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Python does not distinguish between single and double quotes.

Here is further information ->
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/single-and-double-quotes-python/